# Cardinality of $\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})(f(x)-x \in \mathbb{N})\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be $\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})(f(x)-x \in \mathbb{N})\}$. Determine the cardinality of S!

My attempt:

I honestly have no clue, I know that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} ,f(x) = x+n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ but other than that no useful conclusions. I can't even seem to intuitively guess this. Of course, $k(S) \leq k(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$, but other than that I'm lost here and would appreciate any hints!

I've tried to build different injections from $P(\mathbb R)$,$\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ and $P(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$ to $S$ but have failed miserably!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in S$, define $g_f$ to be $g_f(x)=f(x)-x$. Then $g_f\in\Bbb{N^{R\setminus Q}}$, define $h_f=f\restriction\Bbb Q$. Note, moreover, that that $f\mapsto (g_f,h_f)\in\Bbb{N^{R\setminus Q}\times R^Q}$ is a bijection.

What is the cardinality of $\Bbb{N^{R\setminus Q}\times R^Q}$?

Comment: The cardinality of that set is $2^c$ ? (where $c=k(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Yes. It is.${}{}$